# Need help in XML transformation to text

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, transformation

I am trying to convert the following XML document to a simple set of text records. This XML document is a comparison report and contains records from source `(<row host="src">)` and target `(<row host="targ">)`. I want the records from source and target to be displayed on a single row.

The `<col></col>` attributes are dynamically generated and would vary for each record.

Could someone help me create an XSLT transformation template for this XML document.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rows>
    <row-diff op="update" row-stat="oos">
        <row host="src">
            <col name="ID" val="165218" diff="n"/>
            <col name="GGROWHASH" hex="y" val="510616A185137C0B" diff="y"/>
            <col name="APPLICATIONID" val="2631718" diff="n"/>
            <col name="APPLICATIONALERTTYPEID" val="2" diff="n"/>
            <col name="ALERTTYPE" val="Business Verification - Underwriting" diff="n"/>
            <col name="MESSAGEERROR" val="Business Verification - Underwriting" diff="n"/>
            <col name="ISPASS" val="0" diff="n"/>
            <col name="ISACTIVE" val="0" diff="n"/>
            <col name="ISVALIDATIONREQUIRED" val="1" diff="n"/>
            <col name="ISHIDELINK" val="0" diff="n"/>
            <col name="CREATEDAT" val="2016-11-04:19:25:17.000000" diff="n"/>
            <col name="CLEAREDAT" val="2016-11-04:19:26:34.000000" diff="y"/>
            <col name="ISSUPPRESSED" val="0" diff="n"/>
            <col name="DESCRIPTION" val=" " diff="n"/>
        </row>
        <row host="targ">
            <col name="ID" val="165218" diff="n"/>
            <col name="GGROWHASH" hex="y" val="CFF873308AFA3EDE" diff="y"/>
            <col name="APPLICATIONID" val="2631718" diff="n"/>
            <col name="APPLICATIONALERTTYPEID" val="2" diff="n"/>
            <col name="ALERTTYPE" val="Business Verification - Underwriting" diff="n"/>
            <col name="MESSAGEERROR" val="Business Verification - Underwriting" diff="n"/>
            <col name="ISPASS" val="0" diff="n"/>
            <col name="ISACTIVE" val="0" diff="n"/>
            <col name="ISVALIDATIONREQUIRED" val="1" diff="n"/>
            <col name="ISHIDELINK" val="0" diff="n"/>
            <col name="CREATEDAT" val="2016-11-04:19:25:17.000000" diff="n"/>
            <col name="CLEAREDAT" val="2016-11-04:19:28:40.000000" diff="y"/>
            <col name="ISSUPPRESSED" val="0" diff="n"/>
            <col name="DESCRIPTION" val=" " diff="n"/>
        </row>
    </row-diff>
    <row-diff op="update" row-stat="oos">
        <row host="src">
            <col name="ID" val="167450" diff="n"/>
            <col name="GGROWHASH" hex="y" val="B3FA385F42FC2B83" diff="y"/>
            <col name="APPLICATIONID" val="2684158" diff="n"/>
            <col name="APPLICATIONALERTTYPEID" val="1" diff="n"/>
            <col name="ALERTTYPE" val="Application Alert" diff="n"/>
            <col name="MESSAGEERROR" val="Application Alert" diff="n"/>
            <col name="ISPASS" val="0" diff="n"/>
            <col name="ISACTIVE" val="0" diff="n"/>
            <col name="ISVALIDATIONREQUIRED" val="1" diff="n"/>
            <col name="ISHIDELINK" val="0" diff="n"/>
            <col name="CREATEDAT" val="2016-11-06:17:09:12.000000" diff="n"/>
            <col name="CLEAREDAT" val="2016-11-06:17:18:15.000000" diff="y"/>
            <col name="ISSUPPRESSED" val="0" diff="n"/>
            <col name="DESCRIPTION" val=" " diff="n"/>
        </row>
        <row host="targ">
            <col name="ID" val="167450" diff="n"/>
            <col name="GGROWHASH" hex="y" val="A507083F74BF5677" diff="y"/>
            <col name="APPLICATIONID" val="2684158" diff="n"/>
            <col name="APPLICATIONALERTTYPEID" val="1" diff="n"/>
            <col name="ALERTTYPE" val="Application Alert" diff="n"/>
            <col name="MESSAGEERROR" val="Application Alert" diff="n"/>
            <col name="ISPASS" val="0" diff="n"/>
            <col name="ISACTIVE" val="0" diff="n"/>
            <col name="ISVALIDATIONREQUIRED" val="1" diff="n"/>
            <col name="ISHIDELINK" val="0" diff="n"/>
            <col name="CREATEDAT" val="2016-11-06:17:09:12.000000" diff="n"/>
            <col name="CLEAREDAT" val="2016-11-06:17:37:29.000000" diff="y"/>
            <col name="ISSUPPRESSED" val="0" diff="n"/>
            <col name="DESCRIPTION" val=" " diff="n"/>
        </row>
</rows>
```

Following is the XSLT template that I am using. This template puts rows from source and target on the same line.

```html
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
   <xsl:template match = "/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <h2>Out Of Sync report</h2>
            <table border = "1"> 
               <xsl:for-each select = "rows/row-diff">
                  <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select = "@op"/></td>
     <xsl:for-each select = "row/col"> 
                     <td><xsl:value-of select = "@val"/></td>
     </xsl:for-each>
                  </tr>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want the values from "name" attribute to be treated as header. Moreover, it would be great, if I can somehow put the records from source and target one after another. Something like as follows

```html
<style type='text/css'>
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, pre, a, table, tr, th, td {
border: 0; font: 10.5pt calibri; font-style: inherit;font-weight: inherit;color: #777; margin: 0; outline: 0;padding: 0; padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; vertical-align: baseline;}
html {-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}
table,tr,td {color:#585858; padding:1px 1px 1px 1px; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; text-align:left;}
table { border: 1px solid #777; border-collapse: collapse; padding-top:10px;}
td { padding:2px 2px 2px 2px; border: 1px solid #777;}
th {font:bold 10.5pt calibri; color:#FFFFFF; background:#DBA901; padding:3px 3px 3px 3px; border: 1px solid #777; text-transform: uppercase; text-align:left;}
th {border-bottom-color: #777; background-color: #DBA901; border-top-color: #777; border-right-color: #777; border-left-color: #777; border-bottom-style: hidden;}
h1 { font-size: 20px; line-height: 35px; color: #777; padding: 20px, 20px,20px,5px;border-bottom:1px solid #777; width:800px;}
.overview_table {width: 250px;}
.red td {color: red;}
.err {color: red;}
</style>

<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Origin</th>
<th>Operation</th>
<th>ID</th>
<th>GGROWHASH</th>
<th>APPLICATIONID</th>
<th>APPLICATIONALERTTYPEID</th>
<th>ALERTTYPE</th>
<th>MESSAGEERROR</th>
<th>ISPASS</th>
<th>ISACTIVE</th>
<th>ISVALIDATIONREQUIRED</th>
<th>ISHIDELINK</th>
<th>CREATEDAT</th>
<th>CLEAREDAT</th>
<th>ISSUPPRESSED</th>
<th>DESCRIPTION</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>src</td>
<td>update</td>
<td>165218</td>
<td>510616A185137C0B</td>
<td>2631718</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>Business Verification - Underwriting</td>
<td>Business Verification - Underwriting</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>2016-11-04:19:25:17.000000</td>
<td>2016-11-04:19:26:34.000000</td>
<td>0</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>targ</td>
<td>update</td>
<td>165218</td>
<td>CFF873308AFA3EDE</td>
<td>2631718</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>Business Verification - Underwriting</td>
<td>Business Verification - Underwriting</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>2016-11-04:19:25:17.000000</td>
<td>2016-11-04:19:28:40.000000</td>
<td>0</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Please share whatever XSLT you have tried so far. Additionally the output also needs to be shared which would reduce the guesswork.

Comment: This shouldn't be too hard to do, but can you clarify the exact output you want. You initially say "I want the records from source and target to be displayed on a single row.", but in the expected output that you show they are on separate rows. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required output can be achieved by modifying the XSLT to perform looping multiple times.

In order to print the header row, you can run a loop on `row-diff[1]/row[1]/col` and hardcode the value of the first 2 columns since their values are not available in the input XML.

```
<tr>
    <th>ORIGIN</th>
    <th>OPERATION</th>
    <xsl:for-each select="row-diff[1]/row[1]/col">
        <th><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></th>
    </xsl:for-each>
</tr>
```

For printing the values, run nested loops as below. Here too, you would need to take care preparing the `<td>` for first 2 columns in the outer loop and the rest of the columns in the inner loop.

```
<xsl:for-each select="row-diff/row">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@host" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="../@op" /></td>
        <xsl:for-each select="col">
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@val" /></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Below is the complete XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="rows">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Out Of Sync report</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ORIGIN</th>
                        <th>OPERATION</th>
                        <xsl:for-each select="row-diff[1]/row[1]/col">
                            <th><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></th>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="row-diff/row">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="@host" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="../@op" /></td>
                            <xsl:for-each select="col">
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="@val" /></td>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output (Added `<style>` to `html` after transformation)

```
<html>
<style type='text/css'>
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, pre, a, table, tr, th, td {
border: 0; font: 10.5pt calibri; font-style: inherit;font-weight: inherit;color: #777; margin: 0; outline: 0;padding: 0; padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; vertical-align: baseline;}
html {-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}
table,tr,td {color:#585858; padding:1px 1px 1px 1px; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; text-align:left;}
table { border: 1px solid #777; border-collapse: collapse; padding-top:10px;}
td { padding:2px 2px 2px 2px; border: 1px solid #777;}
th {font:bold 10.5pt calibri; color:#FFFFFF; background:#DBA901; padding:3px 3px 3px 3px; border: 1px solid #777; text-transform: uppercase; text-align:left;}
th {border-bottom-color: #777; background-color: #DBA901; border-top-color: #777; border-right-color: #777; border-left-color: #777; border-bottom-style: hidden;}
h1 { font-size: 20px; line-height: 35px; color: #777; padding: 20px, 20px,20px,5px;border-bottom:1px solid #777; width:800px;}
.overview_table {width: 250px;}
.red td {color: red;}
.err {color: red;}
</style>
    <body>
        <h2>Out Of Sync report</h2>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>ORIGIN</th>
                <th>OPERATION</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>GGROWHASH</th>
                <th>APPLICATIONID</th>
                <th>APPLICATIONALERTTYPEID</th>
                <th>ALERTTYPE</th>
                <th>MESSAGEERROR</th>
                <th>ISPASS</th>
                <th>ISACTIVE</th>
                <th>ISVALIDATIONREQUIRED</th>
                <th>ISHIDELINK</th>
                <th>CREATEDAT</th>
                <th>CLEAREDAT</th>
                <th>ISSUPPRESSED</th>
                <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>src</td>
                <td>update</td>
                <td>165218</td>
                <td>510616A185137C0B</td>
                <td>2631718</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Business Verification - Underwriting</td>
                <td>Business Verification - Underwriting</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>2016-11-04:19:25:17.000000</td>
                <td>2016-11-04:19:26:34.000000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>targ</td>
                <td>update</td>
                <td>165218</td>
                <td>CFF873308AFA3EDE</td>
                <td>2631718</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Business Verification - Underwriting</td>
                <td>Business Verification - Underwriting</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>2016-11-04:19:25:17.000000</td>
                <td>2016-11-04:19:28:40.000000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>src</td>
                <td>update</td>
                <td>167450</td>
                <td>B3FA385F42FC2B83</td>
                <td>2684158</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Application Alert</td>
                <td>Application Alert</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>2016-11-06:17:09:12.000000</td>
                <td>2016-11-06:17:18:15.000000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>targ</td>
                <td>update</td>
                <td>167450</td>
                <td>A507083F74BF5677</td>
                <td>2684158</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Application Alert</td>
                <td>Application Alert</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>2016-11-06:17:09:12.000000</td>
                <td>2016-11-06:17:37:29.000000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and the solution. It worked for me.